# posting json data with curl and failing

Tags: php, json, curl

I have this function here:

```
public static function call($action, array $args) 
{
  $post_args = array(
                'action'  => $action,
                'args'    => $args
               );
  $stream    = json_encode($post_args);
  $headers   = array(
                 'Content-type: application/json',
                 'Accept: application/json',
                 'Expect:'
               );
  $userpwd   = self::$_user.':'.sha1(sha1(self::$_pass));

  $ch   = curl_init();
  $args = array(
           CURLOPT_URL            => self::$_url,
           CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
           CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
           CURLOPT_POST           => TRUE,
           CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $stream,
           CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers,
           CURLOPT_USERPWD        => $userpwd
          );
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $args);
  $res  = curl_exec($ch);
  $data = json_decode($res, true);
  if (isset($data) === TRUE
      && empty($data) === FALSE
  ) {
    $res = $data;
  }
  return $res;

}//end call()
```

and at the URL where I'm posting, I'm just doing:

```
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```

but getting nothing, even though I do post data. What could be the problem? I'm at a dead end.

Also, why do I need CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION set to TRUE when I'm just posting to a simple virtual host URL on my local machine, not doing any redirects.

**EDIT:**

tried redoing it with fopen like so:

```
public static function call($action, array $args) 
{
  $post_args = array(
                'action'  => $action,
                'args'    => $args
               );
  $stream    = json_encode($post_args);

  $userpwd   = self::$_user.':'.sha1(sha1(self::$_pass));

  $opts = array(
           'http' => array(
                      'method'  => 'POST',
                      'header'  => array(
                                     "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($userpwd),
                                     "Content-type: application/json"
                                   ),
                      'content' => $stream
                     )
          );

  $context = stream_context_create($opts);

  $res = '';
  $fp = fopen(self::$_url, 'r', false, $context);
  if($fp){
    while (!feof($fp)){
      $res .= fread($fp, 128);
    }
  }
  return $res;

}//end call()
```

no success. The connection works with curl and with fopen, since I pass the status along with result (which is just the php://input stream). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem.

I was calling http://localhost/api, since I thought that it would load the index.php automatically, and then I was going to change the default file name for the folder.

The problem was that I didn't add index.php at the end - I should've called http://localhost/api/index.php. 
This way it worked with cURL and with fopen.

Any ideas how to call the API without revealing the filename?

Comment: Put a .htaccess file into the folder where you put your php. in htaccess write those down:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* myfile.php [PT,L]

All requests go to myfile.php.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I get a Moved Permanently 301 response, and if I set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to true, I get an empty result just like before.

Comment: http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html  Check this out. May help you to write htaccess correctly. Maybe you have written wrong. And more thing, try to write something, maybe date time, or maybe the request you have sent, into a file in php file. So you can understand it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be sure about that curl_exec function ends successfully. Also, why don't you use fopen for this purpose. I have written a JSON RPC client and server. I'm sending requests with fopen, and it works perfect.

```
        $httpRequestOptions =
            array(
                'http'=>array(
                    'method'=>'POST',
                    'header'=>'Content-type: application/json',
                    'content'=>$requestJSON
                )
            );

        $context = stream_context_create($httpRequestOptions);

        // send request
        if($fileHandler = @fopen($serverURL, 'r', false, $context)){
```

I'm not writing the rest. You can use this code I have written.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure curl_exec ends successfully because I'm echoing a json encoded array also containing status integer, and I get that part of the array. I'll try rewriting the function with fopen.

Comment: I redid it with fopen, but still no luck getting data with file_get_contents('php://input'); even though it read the status.

Comment: Just to be sure about it, you are writing a URL to serverURL part, right? instead of a file path. It must be something like, `http://localhost/server.php`. If you write `server.php` or something like it, it doesnt work. Sent parameters don't pass to `php://input`

Comment: Your comment made me recheck my URL. Thanks.